# Not Getting Expected Output when Using a Stack

Tags: java, stack

I'm working on a program that converts an infix expression and outputs a postfix expression. The code below runs without error, but doesn't return the output I'm expecting.

For example, if I supply the element 'infix' with the string `1 + 2`, I'd *like* the output to be `1 2 +`. Right now it comes out as `1  2+` (Two spaces between 1 and 2, and no space between 2 and +). Can anyone provide me with some guidance/thoughts on how to get return a string with one space between each character in the string?

```
public static String infixConvert(String infix) {

    //create a string to contain the converted formula, and a stack to make the conversion in

    String convertedPostfix = "";
    Stack<Character> mathFunction = new Stack<Character>();
    char poppedVal;

    //start a loop to process the conversion from infix to postfix

    for (int x = 0; x < infix.length(); x++) {

        //create an object to reference the character being evaluated

        char character = infix.charAt(x);

        //Call the numOrChar method to first check if the character is a number or a math function. If it's a number, add the character to convertedPostfix

        if (numOrChar(character) == false)

            convertedPostfix = convertedPostfix + character;

        //If the character is a right-side bracket (but not a left-side one), then increment convertedPostFix by the poppedVal

        else if (character == ')')
            while ((poppedVal = mathFunction.pop()) != '(')
                convertedPostfix = convertedPostfix + poppedVal;

        //For all other scenarios, update convertedPostFix to include the top element in the stack (should be a math function)

        else {
                while (!mathFunction.isEmpty() && character != '(' && priority(mathFunction.peek()) >= priority(character))
                    convertedPostfix = convertedPostfix + mathFunction.pop();
                        mathFunction.push(character);
            }
    }

    //Pop the remaining operators in the stack

    while(!mathFunction.isEmpty())
        convertedPostfix = convertedPostfix + mathFunction.pop();
    return convertedPostfix;

    }

    //Method to determine if the character is a number or non-numeric character

    public static boolean numOrChar(char x) {
        return priority(x) > 0;
    }

    //Method to determine the importance of the non-numerical characters in the string

    public static int priority(char x) {
        if (x == '(')
            return 1;

        else if (x == ')')
            return 1;

        else if (x == '+')
            return 2;

        else if (x == '-')
            return 2;

        else if (x == '*')
            return 3;

        else if (x == '/')
            return 3;

            else return 0;

    }
```

**EDIT** I added a new String at the top of my method that removes the white spaces from the entered string.

```
public static String infixConvert(String infix) {

    //create a string to contain the converted formula, and a stack to make the conversion in

    String convertedPostfix = "";
    Stack<Character> mathFunction = new Stack<Character>();
    char poppedVal;
    String infixNoSpace = infix.replaceAll("\\s","");

    //start a loop to process the conversion from infix to postfix

    for (int x = 0; x < infixNoSpace.length(); x++) {

        //create an object to reference the character being evaluated

        char character = infixNoSpace.charAt(x);
```

Comment: `[teach-me]` Your code is treating `1 ` (one followed by space) and ` 2` (space followed by 2) as numbers. However, in reality, only `1` and `2` are numbers, and space is irrelevant. Please treat space differently from the digits. Once you ignore spaces in input, you'll need to add them to output.

Comment: You are disregarding the spaces in input. Split the string by spaces first, then save numbers and operators to another array. Then convert array. Finally add spaces to output.

Comment: `while (!mathFunction.isEmpty() && character != '(' && priority(mathFunction.peek()) >= priority(character))` Are you sure you want a while here?  If you have the wrong inputs, that ends up being an infinite loop.  Specifically, if the priority of the current entry is less than the priority of the top element of the stack.

Comment: @Arkadiy, I modified my code just a touch to remove spaces from the string. Is that what you're trying to send me towards (I would still need to manipulate the string at the end to add the spaces back in).